# Which site-generator can I use?

Tags: generator, static-site

I need a static site-generator with the following characteristics:

- **simple**: I don't want to be obliged to learn a new language to create a site (unless it is html, css, markdown, etc.);
- **open**: it has to be free (as in freedom), or open-source;
- **themed**: I need something aesthetically acceptable.

The site has to be hosted on gitlab.

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You might check [Eleventy](https://11ty.dev), which allows [considerable freedom in templating](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/) including, yes, HTML and Markdown, although you obviously won't have all the flexibility you'd get from using a programming language.